# How To Call Phone Number In Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I make a phone call or dial a number in Android Kotlin? For example: Call `*21*2#`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is a java example :

On call button click:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Permission in Manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: He asked about kotlin code not java

Comment: Android studio will convert Java code to Kotlin, Dont forget the permission in manifest. If you dont add that the dialler will open without the number you specify.

Comment: val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"))
startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Anko library you could simple call this function

```
makeCall(number)
```

[Link](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents) for Anko library.

If you are not using this library, then do this:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$number")
startActivity(intent)
```

Don't forget to add permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: thanks , i will learn about this then i will back :)

Comment: You should use Intent.ACTION_DIAL, it will open the phone dial and let the user the choice to start or not the call. Then you will no need the permission anymore.

Comment: I agree with j.seisson, you should consider using ACTION_DIAL instead. It's easier to implement, plus it handles calls the same as the Text Utility Linkify.